# PHP - Autocomplete for magic method that receives the returning class as argument

Tags: php, phpstorm, magic-methods

Having:

```
$ApiTokenService = Loader::get("App\\Services\\ApiTokenService");
```

How do I document `get()` method to let it know that first param would be the returning output type?
So whenever i start typing $ApiTokenService->cr.. i get create method suggest that ApiTokenService has.

I'm using PhpStorm as IDE.
I've tried things like

```
 /**
 * @param string $classPath
 * @return {$classPath}
 */
```

But nothing has worked so far.

And PHPStorm metadata file:

```
<?php
    namespace PHPSTORM_META {
        override(\Loader::get(), type(0));
    }
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do exactly. Documentation is not something you can use dinamically. Your return values will be mixed, so either put that or "object", which is general enough but still narrows it down.

Comment: I want to have autocomplete available for the returning class, so if ApiTokenService has "createToken" for example, i expected PHPStorm to display that method once i start typing "$ApiTokenService->cr.."

Comment: You cannot do that with PHPDoc (for `get()` method I mean) unless you want to typehint the actual `$ApiTokenService` variable (with a standard `@var` tag). Better use **Advanced Metadata** functionality -- it is made exactly for that (and more) -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#override. Quite few tools use that, e.g. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper for Laravel (example file: https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/bb6ffc5d11e0a75dba67)

Comment: Oh, forgot to say i also tried it, but doesnt make any diff:
<?php
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    override(\Loader::get(), type(0)); 
}

Comment: @FrakyDale Seems to work for me: https://postimg.cc/QFMsx0cM may take some time for IDE to parse/refresh it...

Comment: @FrakyDale Same with `FQN::class` usage (which is recommended to useover a hardcoded string value) -- https://postimg.cc/LhHmb9hf

Comment: oh, facepalm, the loader was receiving class namespaces with double \ . Now it's working properly, ty!